# Mysql social network follower query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am making a social networking application and now i am trying to make the database for the application.

I have 2 tables `user table` and `follower table`. Table structure look like this

```
user table                          follower table
----------------                   ----------------
    userid (int)                     userid  
    username                         follower id   
----------------
```

I am trying to list all followers of a user. I need the followers username in the result. I don't know how to do it. Any help would be much appreciated. thanks.

Comment: What's your foreign key constraints?

Comment: i don't have a foreign key. There's no relations specified.

Comment: then what's your database look like? any example data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `"follower id"` (hopefully not the actual column name) is a foreign key reference to `user(userid)`, a simple join query should suffice

```
SELECT u.userid, u.username
FROM `follower table` f
INNER JOIN `user table` u on f.`follower id` = u.userid
WHERE f.userid = :userid -- the ID of the user who's followers you're after
```

Comment: dude why FROM clause  using the follower table. can u explain ??

Comment: @user2967888 It doesn't really matter which table is in the `FROM` vs `JOIN` in an inner join operation. For me it's personal preference to use the table on which the predicate (`WHERE f.userid = :userid`) applies

Comment: Phil is this database structure ok ?. any recommendations ?. @Phil

Comment: @user2967888 Looks OK to me. I'd just use saner table / column names (spaces make things difficult) and enforce foreign key constraints. The primary key for the "followers" table should also be a composite of `userid` and `follower id` if it's not already

Comment: do i need a junction table @Phil ?. Apparently this scenario is many to many right ?

Comment: @user2967888 your *followers* table **is** a junction table and yes, it's *many-to-many*, just between the same table, ie `users <- followers -> users`